# Cannot install package XML to R

Tags: xml, r

I need to install the package "XML" to R. It always reports "XML is not available for R(Version 3.1.1)"
I have tried to download the .tar but it still did'n work. Can anyone help me to solve this?

```
> install.packages("XML", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R");
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.omegahat.org/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.1

   package ‘XML’ is available as a source package but not as a binary

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘XML’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1)
```

Comment: Why aren't you just installing the binary from CRAN?

Comment: For whatever reason, it doesn't look as if omegahat is hosting a compiled [3.1 repository](http://www.omegahat.org/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.1) (but they do have a [3.0 repository](http://www.omegahat.org/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.0)). As the error message states, it is avialble in "source" form rather than binary: `install.packages("XML", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R", type="source")`

Comment: I have tried this...it didn't work

Answer (score 17):

In general, `install.packages("XML")` worked well for me in the past, but I recently had an issue with R version 3.6.3.

The solution for me was:

```
install.packages("XML", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R")
```

Note that it's **.net**, not **.org**.

Comment: Yes, found the same hardway

Comment: Also worked on R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15). Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

When installing on Windows, I have to first make sure the `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.2\library` folder was not read only and editable by the current user.

1. Navigate to `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.2\`
2. Right click on the `library` folder
3. Click `Properties`
4. Select the `Security` tab
5. Click the `Edit...` button
6. In `Group or user names`, select the `Users` row
7. In the `Permissions for Users`, ensure `Full Control` is checked

Then I had to run

```
install.packages("XML", type = "binary")
```

After this, running `require(XML)` worked.

Comment: Strange, I wouldn't think this would have worked, but it did for me.

Comment: The only necessary part for me was to specify "binary".

Comment: install.packages("XML", type = "binary") worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
install.packages("XML")
```

It worked for me.

```
install.packages("XML", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R");
```

The above code returned the same error for me as well. I am also using R 3.1.1

Answer (score 2):

try `sudo apt-get install r-cran-xml`, it works on my machine with R == 3.6.3, ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. However, I installed xml in conda separately using the following command and it worked out for me

```
conda install -c r r-xml
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Unable to install R package due to XML dependency mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37035088/unable-to-install-r-package-due-to-xml-dependency-mismatch) the `conda` way

`$ conda install -c r r-xml=3.98_1.5`