# GenomicFeatures Installation and Loading Error "there is no package called ‘GenomicFeatures" via Python3 rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am trying to use the Bioconductor GenomicFeatures objects and methods via python rpy2 so when I execute the following code:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

robjects.r('install.packages("XML", '
        'repos="http://cran.r-project.org")')
robjects.r('install.packages("BiocManager", '
       'repos="http://cran.r-project.org")')
robjects.r('BiocManager::install("GenomicFeatures ")')

robjects.r('library(GenomicFeatures )')
```

I get the corresponding error:

```
ERROR: dependency ‘XML’ is not available for package ‘rtracklayer’ 
* removing ‘/Users/nalomran/opt/anaconda3/envs/ReQTL/lib/R/library/rtracklayer’
ERROR: dependency ‘XML’ is not available for package ‘biomaRt’
* removing ‘/Users/nalomran/opt/anaconda3/envs/ReQTL/lib/R/library/biomaRt’
ERROR: dependencies ‘rtracklayer’, ‘biomaRt’ are not available for package ‘GenomicFeatures’
* removing ‘/Users/nalomran/opt/anaconda3/envs/ReQTL/lib/R/library/GenomicFeatures’
R[write to console]: Error in library(GenomicFeatures) : 
 there is no package called ‘GenomicFeatures’
R[write to console]: 1: package ‘XML’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3) 
R[write to console]:  installation of package ‘GenomicFeatures’ had non-zero exit status

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "annotate_cis_trans.py", line 64, in <module>
robjects.r('library(GenomicFeatures)')
File "/Users/nalomran/opt/anaconda3/envs/ReQTL/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 416, in __call__
res = self.eval(p)
File "/Users/nalomran/opt/anaconda3/envs/ReQTL/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 197, in __call__
return (super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self)
File "/Users/nalomran/opt/anaconda3/envs/ReQTL/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 125, in __call__
res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
File "/Users/nalomran/opt/anaconda3/envs/ReQTL/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/conversion.py", line 44, in _
cdata = function(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/nalomran/opt/anaconda3/envs/ReQTL/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface.py", line 621, in __call__
raise embedded.RRuntimeError(_rinterface._geterrmessage())
rpy2.rinterface_lib.embedded.RRuntimeError: Error in         library(GenomicFeatures) : 
there is no package called ‘GenomicFeatures’
```

I am using Python3.8 with conda env for rpy2, how can I solve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you using a conda env for rpy2 or is it a docker image?

Comment: Hi @MiguelTrejo, using conda env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully I was able to fix the issue I was having with the installation and loading of the Bioconductor `GenomicFeatures` from within python3.8 via `rpy2` .I spent hours reaching that solution so I wanted to share the solution of what I did so that if whom end up with the same issue can find it.

Basically, when tracking the error log, it seems that the actual error was pointing to this particular error line:

```
R[write to console]: 1: package ‘XML’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)
```

As I did some researching I found this particular StackOverflow issue [Cannot install package XML to R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042751/cannot-install-package-xml-to-r) where they were not able to install the package xml to R and GenomicFeatures  needs that package so I add the following line before installing the BiocManager (in case BiocManager is not installed):

```
robjects.r('install.packages("XML", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R")')
```

This answer is taking from @Jaeyoung Chun of the aforementioned StackOverflow issue.

After running the modified code (find below), I was able to install and load such a package without any error or issue:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

robjects.r('install.packages("XML", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R")')
robjects.r('install.packages("BiocManager", '
   'repos="http://cran.r-project.org")')
robjects.r('BiocManager::install("GenomicFeatures ")')

robjects.r('library(GenomicFeatures )')
```